# Apple Health Won't Add Data

Tags: iphone, ios, health.app

There are times when I'm not able to manually add data to the Apple Health app - I provide all of the information and click the "Add" button only to receive a greyed-out button, no new data, and an app that I have to force quit.

It also seems (as I've just confirmed with a reboot of my phone) that I was unable to see data that I'd entered previously at the top of the screen. After the reboot, I *am* able to enter data again.

Example video showing inability to add data (but also showing the absence of existing data): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYHb-JCfElE&feature=youtu.be

Has anyone else seen this happening? Is there something I can do to fix this short of rebooting when it happens?

I noticed in one of my apps that uses Health for part of its data store that occasionally I could click the button, but the app would not actually record data. Then last night, I was trying to record some other data manually in Health, and I experienced the same issue.

iPhone 7, iOS 11.4 Beta (not sure which sub-version) - I've had this device since soon after the iPhone 7 was released.

Comment: Was this working prior to installing the beta?

Comment: It's been doing this off and on for many months. I would say yes, but I'm not 100% certain of that fact.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to update to the release version of 11.4?  That alone might resolve your issue.

Comment: @fsb Just to close this loop, I did remove the beta profile from my device and installed the 11.4 Release - two nights ago, this happened again. It worked fine Tuesday night (26-27) and then Wednesday night (27-28) it stopped. So I'm thinking its unrelated to the beta, sadly.

Comment: Importantly, the in-device pedometer is recording data - once I reboot, it's sent to the Health app (whether it's already there or not is a different question that I can't seem to answer) and displays correctly. It seems to be reading the data and having third party apps writing the data that goes wonky.